# Should i store hashids in database or decode them on every request?

Tags: url, hashids

I`m going to use hashids instead of database ids in my urls, should I dedicate a field to them in database table or encode ids to hashids on url generation and decode hashids to ids on incoming requests?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your platform.  Encoding and decoding on the fly will take usually longer than just looking up a field in a database, especially if the URL is accessed very often.

When storing in a database, the only caveat is the size of the field you are using to store the hashid. Just make sure the field width is wide enough to hold  the largest possible hashed ID that you may have.